# How to get the Name of the cell from the firsTableViewController and to show that on the secendView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to show the name of the cell that was selected on my `UITableView`,
how can I do that? (in Swift)

The problem is that I'm not completely sure if I'm given that currently from the FirstViewController with the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath(_:)` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont Understand your language completely, But what i understood is that you want the text of the selected cell from `tableView` from `ViewController1` and display it in `ViewController2`. So the answer I would suggest is take the text from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` like :

`Objective C -`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 // now you can use cell.textLabel.text
}
```

`Swift` -

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();

let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell;

println(currentCell.textLabel!.text)
```

and assign that `textLabel` to `NSUserDefaults` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` block like

`Objective C`

```
NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [def setValue:cell.textLabel.text  forKey:@"SomeKey"];
    [def synchronize];
```

`Swift` -

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(cell.titleLabel,text, forKey: "someKey")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

and then you can access it anywhere in your program. like

`Objective C` -

```
 NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
 someLabel.text =  [def valueForKey:@"someKey"];
```

`Swift` -

```
var returnValue: [NSString]? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("someKey") as? [NSString]
```

This is the easiest way i used, However theres a different way by using `segue` block to pass data from `ViewController1` and display it in `ViewController2`..  Hope this helped.

Comment: Hey tanks, thats what i was searching, but how would it be in Swift?

Comment: You are welcome my friend.. I First forgot to add code for Swift, But Now I have added it.. Please check..

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way with segue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "detailView") {
        var vc = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
        var indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        vc.FirstString = FirstTableArray[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Here you don't need `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` with this case.

In your nextView create one Instance which will hold value from first view:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var TextView: UITextView!

    var FirstString = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        TextView.text = FirstString
    }
}
```

Hope it will help.